# How to send the name attribute of <td> to a function?

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I have

```
  <td id='<?php echo $id;?>' name='StructuralDataLoaded' onclick='javascript:SelectStatus(id,name);'>
             <?php echo
                "<a>" . $arrayD['Structural Data Loaded'];. "<img   src='images/edit.png'></a>";
              ?>
            </td>
```

and this is SelectStatus function

```
       function SelectStatus(id,name) {

     console.log(id);
     console.log(name);

    var idvalue=id;
    var SelectingStatus = $('#SelectingStatus');
    SelectingStatus.dialog({
        close: function(event, ui) {

        },
        modal: true,
        title: 'Status' ,
        width: 400,
        height: 'auto',
        overlay: {
            backgroundColor: '#000000',
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        buttons: {
          'Save' : function PostData(){
    var data = $('#selected option:selected').val();
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
    var request = $.ajax({
    url: "InsertData.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
    id : idvalue,
    data : data,
    type : name,
    },
    dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function( ) {
    location.reload();
    });
    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
},
          'Return': function(){$(this).dialog('destroy');}
      }

    });// End dialog

 }
```

but the console only shows the id and does not show the name. What is my mistake? and how can I send the name to the SelectStatus function?I am using SelectStatus function for other cells of the table. So I have to send the name of each table to know which cell was edited and then update the database.

Comment: It may be easier to just pass "this" as an argument, and then simply get attribute (from inside the function) as var name = this.getAttribute("name");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the attribute

```
onclick='javascript:SelectStatus(id,this.getAttribute("name"));'
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. So why for sending id I could just write id, but I could not write name?

Comment: Because every DOM element has an `id`, so JavaScript uses that. You could also say `this.id` and be just as correct.